# How did The Ones make the Killiks Force-sensitive?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

In the *Fate of the Jedi* series, the Killiks mentioned that The Ones joined the hive mind and then left it, taking all their powers with them. When they joined, they had granted the Force-sensitivity in order to build Centerpoint and Sinkhole station. **How did The Ones grant the Force-sensitivity to the Killiks in the first place?**